# using comma operator in the body of a loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a while loop in two different ways and noticed that using ',' in the condition twice doesn't work the way I think it does. I'm just curious about what actually happens. Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, lim = 1000, c;
    char s[lim];
    while (i < lim - 1, (c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            s[i] = c;
        }
        else
        {   
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, lim = 1000, c;
    char s[lim];
    while (i < lim - 1, (c = getchar()) != '\n', c != EOF)
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you think it does? Afaik the comma operator simply returns one of the two values. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558/2550406

Comment: Don’t use comma in loops. It means it will ignore all but last condition. Use and/or

Comment: All the comma'd expressions will be evaluated, and the value of the final one controls the loop. Consider using the logical `&&` but beware of short-circuit and side-effects.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wasn't aware of what the coma does. The point of the exercise was to not use && or ||.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", s);` is UB.  `s` is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.  Add `s[i] = 0;` after the loop.

Answer (score 5):

Lets look at the while condition:

```
i < lim - 1, (c = getchar()) != '\n', c != EOF
```

The first part, `i < lim -1` has no effect whatsoever. The second part will execute `c = getchar()`, but the comparison with `'\n'` is completely discarded. The return value of the whole condition is that of `c != EOF`. So the condition is equivalent to:

```
(c = getchar()) != EOF
```

What you can do is to change the comma operator for `&&` instead.

```
i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma does not make complex logical operations. You need to use logical operators instead